# Should I write tests for dependent: :destroy in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I don't get the point of testing if dependent: :destroy in Rails works in my Rails application.
The developers of Ruby on Rails have already tested the function, haven't they?

Is the reason why I should that it will assure the existence of the dependent: :destroy configuration in model?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DHH says "Don’t test standard Active Record associations, validations, or scopes." https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa Is a dependent-destroy association a standard association?

Answer (score 0):

What you are testing isn't the function itself but that logic that your application uses. If it is required for the functionality, testing can validate that it works as expected and that it ***continues*** to work as expected.

This is super useful when you are refactoring, or working on older code and want to be able to validate that it is working as expected quickly.